# Mustn't we add some verb at the end of this sentence to make the meaning more clear?

Tags: sentence-construction

This is a paragraph from some Korean SAT preparatory material.

> As a pillar of its religion of progress and cult of technology, our society cultivates its great illusion, which is related to time. It leads modern man to believe that technological progress will enhance his quality of life far more than the machines, the means of transport, and communications of the last century."

1. Don't we have to add some verb at the end of the second sentence to make it complete? For example, "It leads modern man to believe that technological progress will enhance his quality of life far more than the machines, the means of transport, and communications of the last century did," seems more correct to me.
2. Shouldn't the comma between "the means of transport, and communications" be deleted? "The means of transport and communications" looks more common chunks of nouns than the one which includes a comma in it, separating them unnecessarily.

Answer (score 1):

> As a pillar of its religion of progress and cult of technology, our society cultivates its great illusion, which is related to time. It leads modern man to believe that technological progress will enhance his quality of life far more than the machines, the means of transport, and communications of the last century [enhanced his quality of life].

The verb phrase in square brackets is not required. This is an example of [verb phrase  ellipsis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis_(linguistics)) where a verb phrase that is present in the first clause need not be repeated in the second clause.

The comma before "and communications" is an [Oxford Comma](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/what-is-the-oxford-comma-and-why-do-people-care-so-much-about-it/). It is optional.

Comment: Thanks a million.